# Postgresql function execution error

Tags: postgresql

I have created two functions. I want to run that functions inside a main function. When I run the main function I get an error. How can I solve this problem?

> NOTICE:  The rows affected scrap_v15=0
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "Select update_scrap_v15()"
>   PL/pgSQL function all_functions() line 15 at SQL statement
>   ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>   HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL all_functions() line 15 at SQL statement

This is my first function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_scrap_v15() RETURNS void  AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
   scrap_d integer;
BEGIN
     update public.scrap_v15_src t2  set scrap =  66 where scrap= 0 and il like '%src%';
     GET DIAGNOSTICS scrap_d = ROW_COUNT;
     RAISE NOTICE 'The rows affected scrap d=%', scrap_d;
END;
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   
COST 100; 
ALTER FUNCTION update_scrap_v15()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

This is my second function

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scrap_type() RETURNS void  AS 
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    scrap_t integer;
  BEGIN
update  public.tmz_001  set scrap_type = '55';
update  public.tmz_001  set scrap_dtu = '55';
GET DIAGNOSTICS scrap_t = ROW_COUNT;    
RAISE NOTICE 'The rows affected scrap d=%', scrap_t;

END;
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   
COST 100; 
ALTER FUNCTION scrap_type()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

This is my main function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_functions() RETURNS void  AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    adm_1 integer; adm_2 integer; 
BEGIN
    Select update_scrap_v15();
    GET DIAGNOSTICS adm_1 = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'affected=%', adm_1;
    Select scrap_type();
    GET DIAGNOSTICS adm_2 = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'affected=%', adm_2;   
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   
COST 100; 
ALTER FUNCTION all_functions()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: `HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.`

Comment: I know. How can I change this function?

Comment: Really? Replace SELECT with PERFORM

Comment: Such as  "PERFORM update_scrap_v15();
    GET DIAGNOSTICS adm_1 = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'affected=%', adm_1;
    PERFORM scrap_type();
    GET DIAGNOSTICS adm_2 = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'affected=%', adm_2;"   ?

Comment: Sure. Did you try and test?

Comment: Yes. İts working. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank the maintainers of PostgreSQL - that error message gave you the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres if function returning `void` type that invoke by `PERFORM`.

Instead:

```
Select update_scrap_v15();
```

Use that:

```
PERFORM update_scrap_v15();
```